# Concat DateTime and int field to string using linq2sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, concatenation

I am try to build a linq to get values from a table in sql server that concats 2 fields in different format, DateTime and Int, into one string. Ie.:

```
var result = from a in db.tbTable select new { a.field1, Description =  a.DateTimeField.Value.ToShortDateString() + " - " + a.Cod_filed };
```

Also, if one of those, or both, of the fields (DateTime and Int) are null? Do i need to do anything else?

Thanx to all

Comment: but if i define in my DB that these fields can be null, can i use some ternary if to check it than only try to concat if both are not null?

I am getting error even when both fields are not null. i mean they have value.

Answer (score 0):

If both `DateTimeField` and `Cod_filed` are `Nullable` then you can try

```
var result = from a in db.tbTable 
            select new 
                  { 
                       a.field1, 
                       Description =  a.DateTimeField.HasValue  
                                        ? a.DateTimeField.Value.ToShortDateString() 
                                        : string.Empty + " - " 
                                      + a.Cod_filed ?? string.Empty 
                  };
```

Comment: even this does not work:
`var result = from a in db.tbTable 
            select new 
                  { 
                       a.field1, 
                       Description =  a.DateTimeField.HasValue  
                                        ? a.DateTimeField.Value.ToShortDateString() 
                                        : string.Empty }`

Error: It's not possible to convert the expression

Comment: @Varois what does 'this does not work' exactly mean? can you post the exception + exception mesage ?

Comment: Unable to convert the expression 'Table(tbLoteAlojado).Where(a => (a.Data_Alojamento != null)).Select(a => new <>f__AnonymousTyped8`2(Num_Lote_Alojado = a.Num_Lote_Alojado, Descricao = IIF((Convert(a.Data_Alojamento.Value) != null), a.Data_Alojamento.Value.ToShortDateString(), Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.String])))))' in SQL and not treat it as a local expression.

Comment: I did remove the concat bit .. so i am trying to run only with the DateTime field, converting it to a string if not null, but ..